# php 5 create global variable within function

Tags: php, function, variables

I'm trying to create a global variable within a function but it isn't passed when I try to echo outside the function.

```
function check_input($data)
{
        if ( preg_match("/http/i", $data)) {$GLOBALS['spam'] = 'yes'; 
}

check_input($data);
echo $spam;
echo $GLOBALS['spam'];
```

Comment: 1. that's not even valid PHP 2. No you don't want to create a global

Comment: Wouldn't it be $_GLOBALS or $_GLOBAL ? Maybe not, but it sure seems like it.

Comment: Plus, you haven't set $data

Comment: shouldn't it be global($spam); and then just $spam in the code.... but I can't think of any reason someone would want to do this. just pass $spam in by reference.

Answer (score 2):

The **correct** course of action would be to `return` the value out of the function, instead of relying on global variables.

```
function check_input($data)
{
    //Note the use of true instead of "yes". 
    //You can do more stuff with true/false.
    if ( preg_match("/http/i", $data)) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

$is_spam = check_input($data);
echo $is_spam; //1 or 0, because that's how true and false display in echo.
```

Also see: **[Why is global state so evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have syntax errors:

```
function check_input($data)
{
        if ( preg_match("/http/i", $data)) { $GLOBALS['spam'] = 'yes'; } //Note the } I've added.
}

check_input($data);
echo $spam;
echo $GLOBALS['spam'];
```

Should do fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global keyword for this

```
function check_input($data)
{
    global $spam;
    if ( preg_match("/http/i", $data)) $spam = 'yes';
}
$data = "http://www.example.com";
check_input($data);
echo $spam;
echo $GLOBALS['spam'];
```

but the question is WHY would you want to do this, a much better approach would be to pass $spam is to the function by reference or return it as a return variable.

```
function check_input($data, &$spam)
{
    if ( preg_match("/http/i", $data)) $spam = 'yes';
}
$data = "http://www.example.com";
$spam = "no";
check_input($data, $spam);
echo $spam;
echo $GLOBALS['spam'];
```

or

```
function check_input($data)
{

    return ( preg_match("/http/i", $data))?'yes':'no';
}
$data = "http://www.example.com";
$spam = check_input($data);
echo $spam;
echo $GLOBALS['spam'];
```